# iOS: get 3 different random elements from an NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, random, nsarray

I have a NSMutableArray of N Integer elements (N>4), I want to get 3 different random elements from this array. I do not really need a perfectly-uniform distribution, just 3 different random elements should be OK. Do you have any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make `NSIndexSet`, and keep adding

```
int value = arc4random() % array.count;
```

items to it until its size gets to `3`. The you know that you have your three indexes.

```
NSMutableIndexSet *picks = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
do {
    [picks addIndex:arc4random() % array.count];
} while (picks.count != 3);
[picks enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"Element at index %ud: %@", idx, [array elementAt:idx]);
}];
```

Comment: I do not really understand from the line `[picks enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"Element at index %ud: %@", idx, [array elementAt:idx]);
}]` . It just print out those 3 elements?

Comment: @DavidNg Yes, this is just an illustration of how you can use the `picks` set. The block in my example prints the there elements and their indexes, but of course you are free to use them in any way you want.

Comment: Thank you. Very nice! I added a Swift 4 version in a separate answer below.

Answer (score 6):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {    
    int index = (int)(arc4random() % [array count]);
    id object = [array objectAtIndex:index];
    [array removeObjectAtIndex:index];
}
```

`arc4random()` returns a random number in the range [0,2^32-1). The remainder when you take the modulus with the size of the array gets you a value between [0,arrayCountLessOne].

If you don't want to change your original data array, you can just make a copy of the array.

Comment: Thanks, I was indeed thinking of `rand()`. Fixed!

Comment: Instead of using `arc4random() % [array count]` you should use `arc4random_unform([array count])` to avoid modulo bias. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29956021/796419

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this more than once from various places in your code then consider doing this: The "Objective C way" is to create a category on NSMutableArray which adds a method `randomObjects`. The method itself should generate three random integers from 0 to the length of the array -1 (`N-1`), then return a set of objects from the array at those indices, as per the other answers here (dasblinkenlight's in particular.)

First, create the category. Create a new header file `NSMutableArray+RandomObject.h`, containing:

```
@interface NSMutableArray (RandomObjects)

- (NSSet *) randomObjects;

@end
```

The `RandomElement` in parentheses is the name of your category. Any class you write that includes this new header file will give all your `NSMutableArray` instances the `randomElement` method.

Then the implementation, in `NSMutableArray+RandomObjects.m`:

```
@implementation NSMutableArray (RandomObjects)

- (NSSet *) randomObjects {
  // Use the code from @dasblinkenlight's answer here, adding the following line:
  return picks;
}

@end
```

And that's basically it. You've effectively added that capability to `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: I would only refactor it into a category when I need to call such a method often enough. If its only used once, a category is way too much overkill for this.

Comment: @JustSid I completely agree. Will add a note to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

Nice answer from dasblinkenlight!

In **Swift 4**:

```
let indexes = NSMutableIndexSet()
if array.count > setSize {
    repeat {
        indexes.add(Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count))))
    } while (indexes.count < setSize)
}
```