# What's the difference between arc4random and arc4random_uniform?

Tags: objective-c, random, arc4random

I've seen old posts about the differences between `random` and `arc4random` in Objective-C, and I've seen answers to this online but I didn't really understand, so I was hoping someone here could explain it in an easier-to-understand manner.

What is the difference between using `arc4random` and `arc4random_uniform` to generate random numbers?

Comment: It means what the readily-available documentation says it means.  Did you have a specific question about the documentation?

Comment: The difference between these two functions in Swift is exactly the same as the difference between these two functions in (Objective-)C(++). They're the same functions, with the same behavior, no matter what language you call them from.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

`arc4random` returns an integer between 0 and (2^32)-1 while `arc4random_uniform` returns an integer between 0 and the upper bound you pass it.

From `man 3 arc4random`:

> arc4random_uniform() will return a uniformly distributed random number less than upper_bound.  arc4random_uniform() is recommended over constructions like ``arc4random() % upper_bound'' as it avoids "modulo bias" when the upper bound is not a power of two.

For example if you want an integer between 0 and 4 you could use

```
arc4random() % 5
```

or

```
arc4random_uniform(5)
```

Using the modulus operator in this case introduces modulo bias, so it's better to use arc4random_uniform.

To understand modulo bias assume that `arc4random` had a much smaller range. Instead of 0 to (2^32) -1, it was 0 to (2^4) -1. If you perform % 5 on each number in that range you will get 0 four times, and 1, 2, 3 and 4 three times each making 0 more likely to occur. This difference becomes less significant when the range is much larger, but it's still better to avoid using modulus.

Comment: Is it between 0 and 5, i.e., 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 are possible values, or is it 0, 1, 2, 3, 4? From documentation, it says "less than" upper bound and not "less than or equal to" upper bound.

Comment: @VanDuTran it is not inclusive of the upper bounds. So {0, 1, 2, 3, 4} in your example.