# Getting "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments" when trying to use arc4random

Tags: ios, swift, arc4random

I am making a simple guessing game in Swift, and have been using `arc4random` to generate a random number. However, when I run the app, it fails and gives me the error message "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments." The code that receives the error message is below:

```
var randomNumber = arc4random(50) + 1
```

I am fairly new to Swift, so please enlighten me!

Comment: Wrong function. Use arc4random_uniform instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29956021/2227743 for explanations.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32552336/generating-random-numbers-with-swift-2/32552511#32552511

Comment: It's not really a Swift problem.  If you open a terminal session and type "man arc4random" it will show you a description of how to use it and related functions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29955823/whats-the-difference-between-arc4random-and-arc4random-uniform/29956021#29956021