# Obj-C - Use one of two image arrays programatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two sets of arrays in my app that consist of 3 images each. Every time my app is used, I want one of the two arrays to be set as array _finalSelection (e.g. each time one or the other should be set to _finalSelection randomly). How can I achieve this?

**ViewController.m**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

     _pageImages = @[@"britt001.png", @"britt02.png", @"britt030.png"];
     _pageImages2 = @[@"britt001.png", @"britt02.png", @"britt030.png"];

     _finalSelection = [one of the two above arrays]; 

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use arc4random() division by 2.

```
_finalSelection = arc4random() % 2 ? _pageImages : _pageImages2;
```

Comment: `_finalSelection = arc4random_uniform(2) ? _pageImages1 : _pageImages2`

Comment: It's better to use `arc4random_uniform(2)` instead as ` % 2` will introduce modulo bias on the random distribution. More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29956021/5329717

Comment: @Kamil.S no modulo bias in case of `% 2`.

Comment: @M.S. You're right `% 2` is indeed a special case and there is no bias (I did benchmark that). I'd still opt for `arc4random_uniform` giving consistent results for arbitrary range. In terms of code maintainability it might make a difference. Anyway thanks for clarifying.